# Always on Top shortcut key in linux mint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

is there any quick way to set a window to 'always on top' mode in linux mint 'cinnamon'?

In windows I created an autohotkey script but I do not know how to set such a command up in linux.

Answer (score 2):

I know you posted this a year ago, but I found your post while looking to do the same thing.

It's strange that this has been left out of Linux Mint's Cinnamon hot keys as there are so many available. Maybe this has been fixed in later versions but I'm still using Linux Mint 13 LTS and it's not available in that version.

I've solved the problem by writing a very simple script to do it using `wmctrl`, which is a program that can send commands to a X Window Manager from the command line. If `wmctrl` is not installed on your machine install it with the command below, you can check if it is already installed with `which wmctrl` which will show the path if it is already installed or show nothing if it isn't installed, AFAIK it is not installed by default in Linux Mint.

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Then create a new (very simple) script which should work with any X Window Manager:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script: window-toggle-always-on-top.sh
#
# Script to toggle the always on top setting of the active window. It is 
# designed to work by being assigned to a system hot key.

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above
exit 0
```

Once the script is created open the Linux Mint keyboard settings, go to 'Custom Shortcuts', and add a custom shortcut, make sure to use the full path to the script you created in the command box. After adding it assign it to a hot key by clicking on 'unassigned' below 'Keyboard Bindings'. Then just press the hot key to toggle the always on top setting of whatever window has the focus.

Explanation of the `wmctrl` command:

```
-r :ACTIVE:        - use the currently active window.
-b toggle,above    - toggle the 'always on top' setting.
```

Hope this helps.